# На чем оптимально написать парсер прайса?

Tags: парсер

VDS сервер Linux CentOS

Мне приходит прайс.

Нужно написать скрипт, который будет по крону запускаться на сервере просматривать прайс, находить информацию в интернете по продуктам и скачивать картинки через прокси.

На каком языке программирования оптимальней всего написать такой парсер?

Вопрос тут появился в связи с тем, что не уверен в возможностях PHP, нагрузки на сервер и завасанием на момент парсинга.

Что касается тех, кто будет предлагать Ruby, не уверен, что она установится на CentOS.

Comment: На бумаге пиши.

Comment: Дерзай питон, и счего вы взяли что раби не установиться на центос? 

Comment: @0xFFh, хорошая штука =)

Comment: @dfhsfhgfj, Ruby на сервер поставится без проблем. Касательно того, что лучше - да по барабану. Такое ведь можно и на баше, наверное, накрутить. Попробуйте и решите для себя, что удобнее персонально для Вас. Откуда я знаю - может у Вас уже есть хороший навык писать такое, например, на Перле...

Comment: @dfhsfhgfj, Вы формат прайса опишите, тогда можно думать, что удобней использовать.

Comment: @Discord, а я уже знаю, *против* кого буду голосовать на выборах. За такое вредительство руки отрывать надо.

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется, надо писать на том языке, на котором вам *удобнее*, хоть на Visual Basic'е. Когда алгоритм будет отлажен, возможны варианты:

1. Чересчур медленно для вашей задачи. Что ж, либо улучшаем алгоритм (это, скорее всего, правильное решение), либо переписываем на более быстрый язык.
2. Ваш язык не поддерживается платформой. Тогда меняем язык на идеологически близкий. В любом случае, портировать готовый код существенно легче, чем писать не неудобном языке с нуля.

Answer (score 1):

на nodejs [можно](http://goo.gl/uNoKB).

Answer (score 0):

Можно и на php.

Во первых, если планируется много запросов (ко многим сайтам), то можно использовать библиотеку 
[`AngryCurl`](https://github.com/2naive/AngryCurl). Она позволяет делать много запросов одновременно.

Для разбора `html` можно использовать библиотеку [`SimpleHtmlDom`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).